# create moving obstacles in stage simulator

Tags: ros, simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working on a project that needs to test a path planning algorithm in a environment with moving obstacles. I am wondering is there any way to create a obstacle in stage that could do some random movements?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260007/create-moving-obstacles-in-stage-simulator/) by [g1y5x3](https://answers.ros.org/users/30129/g1y5x3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stage has some support for built-in controllers. There is a randomly-wandering controller included. You can use this to create moving obstacles by adding additional robots that are controlled by the wander controller (or your own controller, if you want a different type of motion).

http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers

If you can't use the inbuilt wander controller, an alternative is to add multiple robots to stage and control them using a ROS node that makes them wander in the way you want. This github repository has samples for using multiple robots in Stage.

https://github.com/gergia/multiple_turtlebots_stage_amcl

Your wander node could either use a map and the navigation stack to randomly set goals (like [this old package](http://wiki.ros.org/random_walk), or it could be a simple ranger-based movement that moves randomly while not running into things.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [g1y5x3](https://answers.ros.org/users/30129/g1y5x3/) on 2017-04-24**:
I have looked into it. But the tutorial is for ROS electric and I tried on kinetic but it doesn't seem working now. Is there any difference when installing the stage_controller into ROS kinetic?

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
The tutorial is for Electric but the wander controller is still included in Kinetic. Unfortunately it appears that stage_ros has a bug that makes the controller ineffective: https://github.com/ros-simulation/stage_ros/issues/32
You need to comment out that line to use the wander controller.